# natbib prints number instead of year

Tags: natbib

I use

```
\usepackage[round, sort, numbers]{natbib}
```

and

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}.
```

Then for cite I use `\citet{Smith}`, in my `.bib` file:

```
@article{Smith,
Author = {Smith, D.A.},
Year = {1999},
Title = {Manipulability measures of common social choice functions},
Journal = {Social Choice and Welfare},
Volume = {16},  
Pages = {639-661},
}
```

in my `.bbl` the output is

```
\bibitem[Smith(1999)]{Smith}
D.A. Smith.
\newblock Manipulability measures of common social choice functions.
\newblock \emph{Social Choice and Welfare}, 16:\penalty0 639--661, 1999.
```

I put `\citet{Smith}`, but get output in my `.tex` file as `Smith(3)`, the number instead of the year. 
How could the author-year be output? like `Smith(1999)`. Any help would be appreciated.

This is my file with all the commands, put into the .cls file

```
 \DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{book}}
 \ProcessOptions\relax
 \ifx\pdfoutput\undefined
    \LoadClass[dvips, a4paper]{book}
 \else
    \LoadClass[pdftex, a4paper]{book}
  \fi


  \usepackage{amssymb}
  \usepackage{graphics} % for improved inclusion of graphics
 \usepackage[margin=10pt,font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption} % for improved       layout of figure captions with extra margin, smaller font than text
  \usepackage{fancyhdr} % for better header layout
  \usepackage{eucal}
  \usepackage[english]{babel}
  \usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
  \usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}
  %\usepackage[round, sort, numbers]{natbib} 
  \usepackage[round, sort, numbers]{natbib}
  %\usepackage[round]{natbib}
  %\usepackage[authoryear,round,colon]{natbib}
  \usepackage{ifthen}
  %\usepackage{multicol} % for pages with multiple text columns, e.g.    References
  \setlength{\columnsep}{20pt} % space between columns; default 10pt quite    narrow
  \usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % correct page numbers for bib in TOC,    nottoc suppresses an entry for TOC itself
  %\usepackage{nextpage}
  %\usepackage{hyperref}
  \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{amssymb}
  \usepackage{amsthm}
  \usepackage{color}
  \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usepackage{pgfplots}
  \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
  \usepackage{caption}
  \usetikzlibrary{trees}
  \usepackage{verbatim}
  \usepackage[rightcaption]{sidecap}
  \usepackage{subcaption}
  \usepackage{bm}
  \usepackage{array}
  \usepackage{enumitem}
  \usepackage{multirow}
  \usepackage{floatrow}
  \usepackage{tabularx}
  \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} 
  \tikzset{
    treenode/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
                  draw, align=center,
                 top color=white, bottom color=blue!20},
root/.style     = {treenode, font=\Large, bottom color=red!30},
env/.style      = {treenode, font=\ttfamily\normalsize},
dummy/.style    = {circle,draw}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Did you try it without option `numbers` for `natbib`? Can you please show us an short compilable code building your bibliography?

Comment: I tried with numbers, I get now Smith[3]... I use a thesis template

Comment: You missunderstood me. try `\usepackage[round, sort]{natbib}`!

Comment: It is a huge file, it calls the external file references.bib with \bibliography{9_backmatter/references}

Comment: I got this error:! Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations. without numbers

Comment: It does not compile at all without number.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the generated files? That is delta all generated aux, bbl, toc etc files, and thee recompile? Aka latex, bibtex, latex, latex

Comment: Yes, I deleted all those files after I make changes in \usepackage[...]{natbib}, but when I try without number, I get the error that Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, let us do it step by step.

First: Your given question: to get the wished result you want please try the following MWE (please see that I only used package `filecontents` to get bib file and tex code together into one MWE):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Smith,
  Author  = {Smith, D.A.},
  Year    = {1999},
  Title   = {Manipulability measures of common social choice functions},
  Journal = {Social Choice and Welfare},
  Volume  = {16},  
  Pages   = {639--661},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[round, sort]{natbib}  % <======================================


\begin{document}

This is text with \cite{Smith} or \citet{Smith}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat} 
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

As you can see you get the result:

[image]

Please run my MWE on your computer and confirm that you get the same result.

## Second:

Your other problem in your comment, it does not compile at all:

Please check in your log file the **first** error, create a new question, add there the first error, change my MWE to show your resulting error (for example by adding an second bib entry giving problems) ...

Comment: I tried it in my thesis.tex file still get the same error.! Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations. does it matter if the documentclass is article or book?